# Restful PHP, method POST get parameter

Tags: php, api, rest

I want to get parameter from url api. http://localhost:8080/api/dangnhap.php/danhsach?id=123

Error: Notice: Undefined index: id in **C:\xampp\htdocs\api\dangnhap.php** on line 15.

Thank.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbwYN.png)

> My resful code

```
private function _input(){
    // code của hàm _input

    $this->params = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
    $this->endpoint = array_shift($this->params);

    $method         = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $allow_method   = array('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE');

    if (in_array($method, $allow_method)){
        $this->method = $method;
    }

    // Nhận thêm dữ liệu tương ứng theo từng loại method
    switch ($this->method) {
        case 'POST':
             $this->params = $_POST;    
        break;

        case 'GET':
            // Không cần nhận, bởi params đã được lấy từ url
        break;

        case 'PUT':
            $this->file    = file_get_contents("php://input");
        break;

        case 'DELETE':
            // Không cần nhận, bởi params đã được lấy từ url
        break;

        default:
            $this->response(500, "Invalid Method");
        break;
    }

}

<?php
```

> My DangNhap.php code

class dangnhap extends restful_api {

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

function danhsach(){
    if ($this->method == 'POST'){
        
        echo($_POST['id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Parameters in the URL are GET, not POST.

Comment: on method POST, how want to get data? (login from, user and pass data) Thank.

Comment: You get the URL data from `$_GET` irrespective of whether the actual request is GET or POST.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a POST, but a GET, try that :

```
 echo($_GET['id']);
```